# Share recylerview adpter with subclass

Tags: android, inheritance, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-viewholder

I have a adapter

SearchAdapter.java:

```
public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private final List<Category> mDataset;

public SearchAdapter(Context c, List<Category> categoryList) {
    mContext = c;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    mDataset= categoryList;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_search_category, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.textView_category.setText(mDataset.get(position).getName());
}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private Button button_sub;
    private TextView textView_category, textView_subCategory;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ...
    }
}
```

Category.java:

```
public class Category {

private Integer id;
private String name;
private String image;
private String createdAt;
private String updatedAt;
private List<Subcategory> subcategories = new ArrayList<Subcategory>(); 

/**getter and setter**/

}
```

SubCategory.java (extending category.java):

```
public class Subcategory extends Category {

private String categoryId;

/**getter and setter**/
}
```

I can create new instance of SearchAdapter without any problem.

```
mAdapter = new SearchAdapter(rootView.getContext(), categoryList);
```

However, I can't pass SubCategory list to the adapter even though its inherited from Category.

```
mAdapter = new SearchAdapter(rootView.getContext(), subCategoryList);
```

UPDATE:
Following is the error message I get:

> EXPECTED PARAMTERS: CATEGORY - 
>   ACTUAL ARGUMENTS: SUBCATEGORY

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: What does "I can't" mean precisely? Error message at compile or run time? Result differing from expected result?

Comment: You need to type cast subCategoryList to CategoryList

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
mAdapter = new SearchAdapter(rootView.getContext(), (Category)subCategoryList);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution thanks to the suggestion from [Ashis Tiwari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156908/ashish-tiwari).

Since its a List, I have to type cast it differently as follows:

```
List<Category> subCategoryList = (List<Category>)(List<?>) item.getSubcategories();
```